# Final String Tokenizer Error in Java

Tags: java

I've written some code that takes in a string of format "1 day hh:mm:ss". Using a string tokenizer, I'm attempting to split the string into various sections of interest, namely convert the 1 day to 86400 seconds, the hours to minutes and so forth. I'm having an error reaching the seconds, and returning that with my code. I can't figure out where the issue lays. I thought about this over the weekend, and as a last resort I've decided to ask the broader community for corrective assistance and any suggestions to improve this code better.

The Goal: Read in a string of format "X days hh:mm:ss" and convert this to seconds. Code is attached below.

This error I get read as follows:

```
   "java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:332)
at ReadIn.parseTime(ReadIn.java:110)
at ReadIn.main(ReadIn.java:60)"
```

I've gathered it has something to do with be unable to parse the final int ("ss") values of the format.I'm not sure why this is so, and would like some clarity was to what I'm doing wrong.

I know some portions of this code are redundant, so I'm completely open and welcome all constructive criticism.

Thanks in advance!

```
 public static int parseTime(String s) {

    int days = 0;
    int hours = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int seconds = 0;

    try{


    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s,": ");
    if(s.contains("day")){

            days = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            String throwAway = st.nextToken();// day
            throwAway = throwAway.substring(0, throwAway.lastIndexOf(throwAway));
            hours = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            throwAway = st.nextToken();//hours
            throwAway = throwAway.substring(0, throwAway.lastIndexOf(throwAway));
            minutes = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            throwAway = throwAway.substring(0, throwAway.lastIndexOf(throwAway));
            seconds = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken());
            throwAway = st.nextToken(); 

        }

    }catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return (days*86400 + hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds*1);

}
```

Comment: You're having an error...? What's the error?

Comment: java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:332)
at ReadIn.parseTime(ReadIn.java:110)
at ReadIn.main(ReadIn.java:60) - Just edited the post for clarity.

Comment: there's no next token, what don't you understand about the exception?

Comment: You need to check if there are more token using `hasMoreTokens()` before calling `nextToken()`. Read the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: throwAway = throwAway.substring(0, throwAway.lastIndexOf(throwAway)); <- This is just hilarious, it doesn't do anything, ever, just substring from 0 to 0. And the result is never used. Just...lovely :d

Comment: By my count your `String` would produce 5 tokens. You're calling `nextToken()` 6 times.

Comment: @BrianRoach - How would I suppress one of the calls? Exclude the final call of nextToken shows errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By my count your String would produce 5 tokens. You're calling `nextToken()` 6 times. And the 6th time is going to throw that exception.

```
 X days hh:mm:ss
 1  2    3  4  5
```

It's also worth mentioning that whatever you're trying to do with those calls to `substring()` ... doesn't do what you think. They don't do anything and you can remove them.

In the end, all you need is:

```
days = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); // token 1
st.nextToken();// // token 2 ("days")
hours = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); // token 3
minutes = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); // token 4
seconds = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()); // token 5
```

the `throwaway` variable isn't needed; simply not assigning the return value from the call to `nextToken()` is going to ... throw it away.

All that said, there are *other* ways to solve this problem. In fact, the [Javadocs for StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) states:

> StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.

Using a regular expression and capture groups, for example, would look like:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d+) days (\\d\\d):(\\d\\d):(\\d\\d)");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(yourString);
if (matcher.find())
{
    days = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    hours = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(2));     
    minutes = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(3));
    seconds = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(4));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is constructive insight.

Comment: I learned something today. Fully comprehend the root cause of the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do the calculation in just one line:

```
public static int parseTime(String s) {
    try {
        return (int) ((new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd 'days' hh:mm:ss").parse("1970-01-" + s).getTime() - new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").parse("1970-01-01 00:00:00").getTime()) / 1000);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

This works because (unbelievably) `SimpleDateFormat` allows more days than actually in the month - it just rolls over to the next month, eg "1970-01-32" is parsed as "1970-02-01", and there's no limit to the number of days this will work with.

You have to subtract the base date due to timezone issues where you are executing this.

Comment: Thanks! I wanted to better understand what I was doing wrong, but this helps too.

Answer (score 1):

Consider simplifying your parsing logic:

```
public static int parseTime( String s ) {
    int days    = 0;
    int hours   = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int seconds = 0;

    try{
        s = s.replaceFirst( "\\s+days?\\s+", ":" );
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer( s, ":" );
        days    = Integer.parseInt( st.nextToken() );
        hours   = Integer.parseInt( st.nextToken() );
        minutes = Integer.parseInt( st.nextToken() );
        seconds = Integer.parseInt( st.nextToken() );

    } catch( NoSuchElementException | NumberFormatException e ) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ( days*86400 + hours*3600 + minutes*60 + seconds );
}
```